# Разница между socket.broadcast.to('some room').emit() и socket.to('some room').emit()

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Уже все перечитал, но никак не могу понять в чем разница между

```
socket.broadcast.to('some room').emit()
```

и

```
socket.to('some room').emit()
```

Answer (score 1):

`io.sockets.emit` - отправит всем клиентам

`socket.broadcast.emit` - отправит всем клиентам, кроме того, кто отправлял сообщение

Comment: Кто там поставил минус, объясните за что. Ответ так-то верный, пусть и прямо из документации без ссылки на оную.

Comment: @D-side Довольно странно, что люди вообще минусуют при этом не описывая, что именно им не нравится (это даже не подходит под мою тему с меты про "неспортивное поведение", т.к. тут нет 2-го конкурирующего ответа :D)

Comment: Имеешь в виду и мне отправит , если я буду в этой комнате? `io.sockets.emit` - отправит всем клиентам